# How to loop over properties of objects at the same time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to loop over two objects at the same time so that I can compare their properties. What I tried was something like

```
for ((prop1, prop2) in (obj1, obj2) {
    console.log(prop1 == prop2)
}
```

which definitely didn't work. How do I do this in js?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function.

```
Object.keys(Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2)).forEach(function(key) {
    var prop1 = obj1[key];
    var prop2 = obj2[key];
    console.log(prop1 == prop2);
});
```

Note: check for browser compatibility of Object.assign() function. Currently it is not supported by IE.

Answer (score 3):

In a basic way, would be it:

```
var obj1 = {
    prop1: 'prop1',
    prop2: 'prop2'
};

var obj2 = {
    prop1: 'prop1',
    prop2: 'prop2',
    prop3: 'prop3'
};

for (var prop in obj1) {
    console.log(prop, obj1[prop] == obj2[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you need to do it in 2 `for`.

```
for (var prop1 in obj1) {
  for(var prop2 in obj2)
    console.log(prop1 == prop2);
}
```

You could try that too, without 2 loops:

```
for (var prop1 in obj1) {
  console.log(obj2[prop1] === undefined);
}
```

Comment: Why am I checking if it's undefined?

Comment: @AlanH: if obj2[prop1] is undefined, it means that obj2 doesn't have prop1 attribute.